# Anypoint Studio - Flow Description in "Message Flow" view

Tags: ide, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

In Anypoint Studio it is possible to add "notes" (descriptions) to our flows:

[image: Flow description]

However the descriptions seem to be only visible in the "Notes" tab in the flow editor.

Of course, this is also visible in the XML view:

```
 <flow name="nameOfMyFlow" doc:description="This flow is doing something. This text is supposed to be describing and documenting the behaviour.

Input:
 - Flow var 1: used to pass some information.
 - Flow var 2: is optional, but it it also used.

This is just some dummy documentation.">
...
```

Is there a way to make these notes/descriptions more visible?

I would be happy to see them in the flow editor when I move the cursor over a specific flow or flow-reference.

I would be happy to see a tooltip like in the Java-Editor:

[image: Tooltip-Java-Editor]

Is something like this already supported in Anypoint-Studio in the flow editor? Can this be configured or is there a plugin that makes something like this possible in the flow-editor?

I would like to make the flow documentation visible and easy to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hover over a component, the notes content is displayed in a tooltip.

[image: Note in a tooltip]

This works for all the other elements, but unfortunately not for flows (at least with Anypoint Studio 6.4.2).

If you hover over other components, then you are going to see the note in a tooltip as you can see above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes. You are right. You can see a tooltip in the case of other components, but I can't do the same for flows. I set a note for the flow, but when I hover over the flow, I don't see any tooltip.